# Flask Javascript delete-note button not wokring

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Can anyone help me with this flask deleteNote button issue?  I'm just starting learning flask. Really appreciate.

I try to describe this problem clearly.  Everything works perfect until I add the deleteNote button. Now i can

notes, but cannot delete note one by one.

[image: 1]

```
Here is my home.html.   I add a deleteNote button here with JavaScript.
```

> ```
> <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
>     <!-- do a for loop to loop all of the notes -->
>     {% for note in user.notes %}
>     <li class="list-group-item">
>         {{ note.data }}
>         <button type="but ton" class="close" onClick="deleteNote('{{ note.id }}')">
>             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
>         </button>
>     </li>
>     {% endfor %}
> </ul>
> ```

Here is my index.js file.  I wrote a deleteNote function.

> ```
> function deleteNote(noteId) {
>     fetch('/delete-note', {
>         method: 'POST',
>         body: JSON.stringify({ noteId: noteId })
>     }).then((_res) => {
>         window.location.href = "/";
>     });
> }
> ```

Here is the views.py file, with homepage Blueprint. Copy the part associate with the deleteNote:

> ```
> @views.route('/delete-note', methods=['POST'])
> def delete_note():
>     note = json.loads(request.data)
>     noteId = note['noteId']
>     note = Note.query.get(noteId)
>     if note:
>         if note.user_id == current_user.id:
>             db.session.delete(note)
>             db.session.commit()
>
>     return jsonify({})
> ```

How to fix this deleteNote button?

Comment: What is the actual problem?  What happens when you click the button?

Comment: Is `noteId` a number (integer)? When you set `"deleteNote('{{ note.id }}')"` you convert number (i.e. `1`) to string (i.e. `'1'`). It is possible that `note = Note.query.get(noteId)` can't be found because `1` and `'1'` are different objects (?Does SQLAlchemy cast types automatically?). So `"deleteNote('{{ note.id }}')"` should be `"deleteNote({{ note.id }})"` in this case

Comment: in this case you have to check types, are they same type or not, get a log for each statements